# C++ : unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

Tags: c++

this is a program use to calculate the marks and grades of 25 students using array.
this is wat my code looks like

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a,b;
char grade;
double mark, sum;
string name;
string studname[25];
double marks[5];
char grades[25];

for (a = 0; a < 25; a++)
{
    sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the student : \n";
    cin >> name;
    studname[a] = name;

    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++)
    {
        cout << "PLease enter the assignment" << b + 1 << "marks : \n";
        cin >> mark;
        marks[b] = mark;
        sum = sum + mark;
    }

    if (sum >= 80)
        grade = 'A';
    else if (sum >= 60)
        grade = 'B';
    else if (sum >= 50)
        grade = 'C';
    else if (sum >= 40)
        grade = 'D';
    else
        grade = 'F';
    grades[a] = grade;

    cout << "Sum of assignment marks : " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Grade : " << grade << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

the output shows :

1>c:\users\ktych\source\repos\lab 5\lab 5\source.cpp(1): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

1>c:\users\ktych\source\repos\lab 5\lab 5\source.cpp(2): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

1>lab 5.vcxproj -> C:\Users\ktych\source\repos\lab 5\Debug\lab 5.exe

1>Done building project "lab 5.vcxproj".

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Get rid of the `;` there `#include <iostream>;`, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it's because of the ; after the include.

E.g. it's the grammar and you must refer to spec and compiler because as an implementation detail the compiler can choose to ignore that.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html